# C# Password validation limit for multiple user login

Tags: c#, mysql

I am attempting to set a login attempt limit. The code allows me to log in to each user, recognizes and invalid attempt, and records the first attempt. BUT it doesn't add up the attempts and then execute the limitation. I originally had the login types as "else if" statements but it would only approve the last login type. Here is my code. Any hints would be greatly appreciated.

```
        private void buttonLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MyDB db = new MyDB();
            int attempt = 1;

            if (attempt < 4)
            {

                MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter();
                DataTable table = new DataTable();
                MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `username` = @usn AND `password` = @pas", db.getConnection);

                command.Parameters.Add("@usn", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = textUsername.Text;
                command.Parameters.Add("@pas", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = textBoxPass.Text;

                adapter.SelectCommand = command;

                adapter.Fill(table);


                if (table.Rows.Count > 0)
                {

                    switch (table.Rows[0]["type"] as string)
                    {
                        case "student":
                            {
                                this.Hide();
                                new StudentMain().Show();
                                break;
                            }
                        case "faculty":
                            {
                                this.Hide();
                                new FacultyMain().Show();
                                break;
                            }
                        case "admin":
                            {
                                this.Hide();
                                new AdminMain().Show();
                                break;
                            }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Invalid Username or Password", "Attempt: " + attempt, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                }
            }

            else if (attempt == 4)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Login attempts exceeded.");
                textUsername.Enabled = false;
                textBoxPassword.Enabled = false;
                this.Close();
            }

            attempt++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you can use **do while** or **while** statements
like do{  // if wrong attempt++ }while(attempt<4)

Comment: @AkbarAsghari that won't work for a Forms app like this. A *while* would lock up the UI. @Char the variable `attempt` is set to 1 every time you click the login button. You need to change it from a variable to a property or field of the parent login form, and only initialize it to 1 when the form is first created

Comment: would you I write sample code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you keep resetting your login attempts each time you click the login button.

Changes this:

```
private void buttonLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ...
    
    int attempt = 1;
    
    ...
}
```

To this:

```
int attempt = 1;

private void buttonLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can write click button function like this logic

```
public int Attempts = 0;
private void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     bool passwordIsTrue = false;

     Attempts++;

     if (Attempts >= 4)
     {
         MessageBox.Show("Maximum attempts (3)");
         return;
     }

     if (passwordIsTrue == false)
     {
         Attempts++; 
     }
     else
     {
         Attempts = 0;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just keep your counter outside the function so when the limit is reached you don´t even have to call the function.